# How to change the background color of current day in the calendar?

Tags: 12.04, colors, calendar, taskbar

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I think the default color for the current day is not right. It lacks of contrast. For usability and accessibility purposes, it's better to highlight a little bit more the current day. How can I do that? Should I send a change / improvement request to Canonical?

Answer (score 3):

What you are going to want to do is submit a bug report against the calendar on Launchpad, a website pertaining to the development, maintenance, and contributions to Ubuntu software.  This what you have to do:

1. Make a launchpad account [here](https://login.launchpad.net/+new_account).
2. Find out exactly which package you have the issue with (when in doubt, submit the report against a more general package, such as unity, then someone can help you change it to the right one) .
3. Make sure that the bug has not already been reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/).
4. Submit the bug report, being sure to be clear and concise.  A general layout to follow is to use 3 headings: "general issue", "what was expected", "what happened instead", "fix/solution/suggestion".

This list applies to any bug you wish to report.

Your contributions are **always** welcome and appreciated by the Ubuntu community.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already posted the bug at Launchpad.